# $r=1-\sin(\theta)$ horizontal and vertical tangents

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, pi, tangent-line

I am having problems determining the horizontal and vertical tangents for $r=1-\sin(\theta)$.

I thought the tangent lines occurred at $\frac{5\pi}6$, $\frac\pi6$, $\frac{3\pi}2$ while the vertical tangent lines occurred at $\frac{11\pi}6$ and $\frac{7\pi}6$.

I solved for $x$ to get $x=\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)\cdot\cos(\theta)$ which produced $-\frac{\sqrt3}4$ for $\frac{5\pi}6$, $\frac{\sqrt3}4$ for $\frac\pi6$, $0$, and $\frac{3\pi}2$.

Comment: It seems completely right so far. You just need to plug in the rest of the numbers and get all the relevant $x$ and $y$ values. Where do you have a problem?

Comment: At first, I was plugging them into my x/y equations which caused a problem. However, I figured out plugging the values into the original equation generated the correct r values. Now, I can't seem to get the vertical tangents correct.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical tangents: Your values of $\theta$ are correct, so we can find the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the intersections by just plugging into $x=\cos\theta(1-\sin\theta)$ and $y=\sin\theta(1-\sin\theta)$. That gives
$$
(x,y) = (\pm \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4},-\frac{3}{4})
$$
So the tangent lines are given by $x=\pm \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$, and they intersect the curve at $y=-\frac34$.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful.So my polar coordinates for the horizontal tangents are: (1/2, 5pi/6), (1/2,pi/6), (2,3pi/2) and my vertical tangents are: (3/2, 11pi/6) and (3/2, 7pi/6) - I'm having some issues with the vertical tangents still. These answers don't seem to be correct.

Comment: I think they are correct. Except there there is actually also a vertical tangent of sorts at the cusp at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, $(r,\theta)=(0,\frac\pi 2)$.